# Verticle line in Sprite Kit asset image

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have created an image to use as an `SKNode(imageNamed: "Background")` and I am also using code to make the background move along from right to left and repeat forever. However, I have a strange line through the background where it repeats and it is very annoying. What could be causing this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.